# Color typo in underline text

Tags: color, soul, underline

Using `soul` package, I try to underline in black a text containing some words. One of the words is colored in grey.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{.5}
\begin{document}
    \ul{Hello \textcolor{Gray}{this} is an example}
\end{document}
```

Produces the error: "Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed."
I tried a dirty solution:

```
\ul{Hello }\textcolor{Gray}{\ul{this}}\ul{ is an example}
```

which doesn't produce error, but underlines my text with a Gray line.
I'd like to underline in black.

> [image: underlineInGray]

Comment: Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Sorry, as there is no special environnement (except soul package in tags) I thought it was clear enought withou MWE. I edited to make it better for future use. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package `soul` can support commands without and with one argument. `\textcolor` uses two arguments, therefore a new command is defined in the following example for `\soulregister`.

The different line color can be fixed by setting the color for the line explicitly using `\setulcolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{.5}
\newcommand*{\ColorGray}{\textcolor{Gray}}
\soulregister{\ColorGray}{1}

\setulcolor{black}

\begin{document}
  \ul{Hello \ColorGray{this} is an example}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]